# Start the gui program as non-root in systemd

Tags: 16.04, gui, systemd, upstart

Run `ps -ef` to find that the process number of upstart is 1566. When the parent process id of my gui program is 1566, it can be displayed normally. Now there are several problems that cause my gui program to not run normally.

1. I have a systemd program, its name is terui. I want to start my gui program in terui. This is my startup code:

   ```
   system("su sunxy -c 'DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/sunxy/.Xauthority /etc/opt/kpki/mw/KCliBaseService/start_tray.sh'");
   ```
2. I found that after starting in this way, the parent process id of the gui program was 1, not 1566, which caused my gui program to fail to display normally. When I enter

   ```
   su sunxy -c'DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/sunxy/.Xauthority /etc/opt/kpki/mw/KCliBaseService/start_tray.sh'
   ```

as a root user in bash, my gui program can be displayed normally, and its parent process id is 1566.

3. This is my terui.service:

   ```
    [Unit]
    Description=terui Daemon
    Requires=network-online.target
    After=network-online.target

    [Service]
    Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
    Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/sunxy/.Xauthority"
    ExecStart=/home/testui/build/terui
    User=root
    Type=simple
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=3s
    [Install]
    WantedBy=graphical.target
   ```

So, my question is, what should I do to display the gui program normally?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So here   you need to change user when the program started with a user   and same user privileges will be applied to the GUI program.

[As per man page of systemctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemctl.1.html) the user parameter  can also be changed as per use case. and Alter the service's possession as well, so the password  warning will be disabled..

**Before**

```
[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/sunxy/.Xauthority"
ExecStart=/home/testui/build/terui
User=root
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=3s
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

**After**

```
[Service]
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/sunxy/.Xauthority"
ExecStart=/home/testui/build/terui
User=USERNAME
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=3s
[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```